# reroute invalid urls back to home in django

Tags: python, django

Using `localhost:8000/admin/` and `localhost:8000/` works fine.

But I want to ignore other meaningless links like localhost:8000/adm and make them route back to localhost:8000/ permanently.

[image: url works fine]

```
from django.urls import path

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import RedirectView


from API import views
from API.views.Home import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^v1/', include('API.urls')),
    url(r'',HomeView.as_view(),name='HomeView'),
]
```

any idea ? can this be simply achieved by regex?

more examples... of what I want to achieve

```
localhost:8000/anything -> localhost:8000/
localhost:8000/anything/ -> localhost:8000/
localhost:8000/admin/anything -> localhost:8000/admin/
localhost:8000/admin/anything/ -> localhost:8000/admin/
```

In short, I want to get rid of excess URL parts, so they don't even show a 5xx redirect in the browser.

It could be easily done in nginx, but I wanted to know if this is easily done in django directly.

Comment: Why would you want that? It's actually good practice to return a 404 Not Found when a page doesn't exist. And it's really bad for search engines if any url points to your home page. Just design a nice 404.html page so users know they entered a wrong URL and get clues as to where to find the content. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/wrong-url)

Comment: ok, at least I want ... localhost:8000/anything to give a 404 page... currently it's showing home page like if i requested localhost:8000

Comment: Perhaps https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/564/displaying-custom-404-error-page-not-found-page-in-django-20/

Comment: @DeyaEldeen: that is because the last view, has no `/` part.

Comment: `r''` matches everything if you only want `/` to match your home page, use `r'^$'`, i.e. the empty URL (starts and ends with nothing in there).

Answer (score 1):

A solution with regex is:

```
url(r'^admin/.', admin.site.urls),
...
url(r'.',HomeView.as_view(),name='HomeView'),
```

but that leaves the original url in the address bar.

To get rid of it, subclass the RedirectView:

```
url(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^admin/.', AdminRedirectView.as_view(), name='admin-redirect'),
...
url(r'^$',HomeView.as_view(),name='HomeView'),
url(r'^.$', HomeRedirectView.as_view(), name='home-redirect'),

# views.py
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

class HomeRedirectView(RedirectView):

    permanent = True
    query_string = False
    pattern_name = 'HomeView'
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the meaning of ...... r'^admin/$' ...... '^admin/.'  ...... r'^$' ...... r'^.$' ......

Comment: Django adds the first slash, so `^admin/$` means `/admin/` exactly and `^$` means exactly `/`. A `.` (dot) means any character any number of times. The point is in order from top to bottom, as the last one `^.$` catches every possible url. `^` is the start, and `$` is the end.